# session in custom JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, session, jsp-tags, dwr

I've a custom tag for loading an image. I pass certain values named picture name and type to the tag and it gets the picture details. I want to load some data related to the current logged in user. For that purpose I need the session in Custom tag.

Is there any way to get the session in Custom tag?
I used the

```
 WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
```

But it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Got the session like this:
Use spring RequestContextHolder:

ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);

Comment: The WebContextFactory method in your question should be used by DWR pojo's (ie., java classes listed in dwr.xml).  For a JSP tag, you can just call pageContext.getSession().